# NSUserDefaults data doesn't show up at first?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

When i start my app, it goes into homeview, and doesn't show any existing palettes saved in NSUserDefaults. But when i click the 'new palette' button and go back, it shows the new one and all of the existing ones. Can't get to the bottom of this. Any help is appreciated.

app delegate.h:

```
@interface palettesAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
 NSMutableArray *colourPalettesContainer;
    NSUserDefaults *prefs;
}
@property (assign, readwrite) NSUserDefaults *prefs;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSMutableArray *colourPalettesContainer;
@end
```

app delegate.m:

```
#import "palettesAppDelegate.h"

@implementation palettesAppDelegate

@synthesize colourPalettesContainer, prefs;

- (void)dealloc {
    [colourPalettesContainer release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Homeview.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HandlingPalettes.h"

@interface HomeView : UIViewController {

    HandlingPalettes *handlingPalettes;

}


@end
```

Homeview.m:

```
#import "HomeView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@implementation HomeView


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
palettesAppDelegate *dataCenter = (palettesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

dataCenter.prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
dataCenter.colourPalettesContainer = [dataCenter.prefs objectForKey:@"palettes"];

handlingPalettes = [[HandlingPalettes alloc] init];

    [handlingPalettes newPalette];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


    NSLog(@"view will appear: %i", [dataCenter.colourPalettesContainer count]);
    int numberOfExisting = [dataCenter.colourPalettesContainer count];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [handlingPalettes release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

HandlingPalettes.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HandlingPalettes : UIViewController {

}


-(void)newPalette;



@end
```

HandlingPalettes.m:

```
#import "HandlingPalettes.h"
#import "HomeView.h"
#import "palettesAppDelegate.h"



@implementation HandlingPalettes


-(void)newPalette {

    palettesAppDelegate *dataCenter = (palettesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //If this is the first palette
    if (dataCenter.colourPalettesContainer == nil) {
    dataCenter.colourPalettesContainer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    //Add a new palette

        [dataCenter.colourPalettesContainer addObject:@"Test1", @"Test2", nil];


    NSLog(@"Handling:    %i", [dataCenter.colourPalettesContainer count]);

    [dataCenter.prefs setObject:dataCenter.colourPalettesContainer forKey:@"palettes"];
[dataCenter.prefs synchronize];
}
- (void)dealloc {
   [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is NSUserDefaults never mentioned in your code?

Comment: `dataCenter.prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];` most likely dataCenter is nil at this point. But there is still a lot of code missing to make a final guess. So I would check if it's nil first.

Comment: fluchtpunkt is probably right, especially if this is loaded as a NIB from an interface-builder-made view. It loads the views before the actual application delegate is instantiated. A general rule of thumb is to not use the application delegate as a "central data source for the app", but instead to use a singleton.

Comment: No, in NIB-powered apps the views are not instantiated before the app delegate. App startup sequence goes like this: main() -> UIApplicationMain() -> read info.plist -> load main XIB (usually MainWndow.xib) -> instantiate app delegate -> call app delegate methods. The problem here is different.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, when you load the app, and your app delegate is called, you do not restore its contents from the NSUserDefaults. You are just creating it if its nil, but that does not solve the problem. You should populate the colourPalettesContainer array with values in your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

Furthermore, Kalle's comment above is relevant; you should not use your app delegate like that. The best approach IMHO is to wrap it in a custom class, that takes care of storing default values at first launch, manages versioning, provides a strongly-typed interface, and can be subclasses if required.